# Estimating shares with multivariate regression

Tags: optimization, multivariate-analysis

I have to **estimate the percentage of land that will be used to harvest different varieties of rice** in Europe. To do this I have observation for the last 20 years for the acreage of every variety and its monthly price. I was thinking of usign as the independent variable the difference between the average price of rice and the price for the single varieties for august (it is the month that shows consistent high correlation for almost all the varieties).
As I am estimating shares, the individual estimates will have to be between 0 and 1 and the sum of the estimates will have to be equal to 1.

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y_1=\beta_{1,0}+\beta_{1,1} x_1 \\
y_2=\beta_{2,0}+\beta_{2,1} x_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_n=\beta_{n, 0}+\beta_{n, 1} x_n \\
y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_n=1
\end{array}\right.
$$

Do you have any suggestions on which model would be best to use for the single estimates? I know logistic regression gives a result between 0 and 1 but i don't know if it is appropriate to use to estimate something that is not a probability.
Also, do you know how I could address the final constraint of the estimates summing to 1?

Any other suggestion about how to approach this problem is vary welcome as well :)

Thank you very much!

P.S. I am estimating the shares and not the acreage per se because while shares are highly correlated with prices while the acreage is not

Comment: This is an optimization problem, not a regression problem.

Comment: could you expand a bit on your problem? what data do you have?